# scilab - how to return matrices from a function with if-statements?

Tags: function, matrix, scilab

I have a scilab function that looks something like this (very simplified code just to get the concept of how it works):

```
function [A, S, Q]=myfunc(a)
  A = a^2;

  S = a+a+a;    

  if S > A then
    Q = "Bigger";
  else 
    Q = "Lower";
  end
endfunction
```

And I get the expected result if I run:

```
--> [A,S,Q]=myfunc(2)
 Q  = 

 Bigger

 S  = 

   6.

 A  = 

   4.
```

But if I put matrices into the function I expect to get equivalent matrices back as an answer with a result but instead I got this:

```
--> [A,S,Q]=myfunc([2 4 6 8])
 Q  = 

 Lower

 S  = 

   6.   12.   18.   24.

 A  = 

   4.   16.   36.   64.
```

Why isn't `Q` returning matrices of values like `S` and `A`? And how do I achieve that it will return "Bigger. Lower. Lower. Lower." as an answer? That is, I want to perform the operation on each element of the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add that in Scilab, the fewer the number of loop, the better : so @luispauloml answer may rewrite to

```
function [A, S, Q]=myfunc(a)
    A = a.^2; // used element wise power, see luispauloml advice
    S = a+a+a;
    Q(S > A) = "Bigger"
    Q(S <= A) = "Lower"
    Q = matrix(Q,size(a,1),size(a,2)) // a-like shape
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in your program you wrote `Q = "Bigger"` and `Q = "Lower"`. That means that `Q` will only have one value. If you want to store the comparisons for every value in `A` and `S`, you have to make Scilab do that.

You can achieve such behavior by using loops. This is how you can do it by using two `for` loops:

```
function [A, S, Q]=myfunc(a)
    A = a^2;
    S = a+a+a;

    //Get the size of input a
    [nrows, ncols] = size(a)

    //Traverse all rows of the input
    for i = 1 : nrows 

        //Traverse all columns of the input
        for j = 1 : ncols 

            //Compare each element
            if S(i,j) > A(i,j) then

                //Store each result
                Q(i,j) = "Bigger"

            else
                Q(i,j) = "Lower"
            end
        end
    end
endfunction
```

**Beware of `A = a^2`.** It can break your function. It has different behaviors if input `a` is a vector (1-by-n or n-by-1 matrix), rectangle matrix (m-by-n matrix, m ≠ n ), or square matrix (n-by-n matrix):

- Vector: it works like `.^`, i.e. it raises each element individually ([see Scilab help](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/dot.html)).
- Rectangle: it won't work because it has to follow the rule of [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).
- Square: it works and follows the rule of matrix multiplication.